# passing object ownership to other thread in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, c#-4.0

**EDIT 1 :**

*Apparently, i have started to achieve a 3D rendering in WPF environment in an incorrect way. Ofc there is a solution for my question here below, but i suggest to read the update of Sheridan's answer and use his recommendations to achieve this. It's not only secure, but also better for performance. Although it's a bit complex to understand it, but once you understand it, you can start rendering multiple 3D applications in WPF.
Thanks for your assistance Sheridan !*

---

Question ;

i am quite new in WPF, and i want to design a continuous rendering (like in gaming applications) with WPF. I am using multithreading to provide a better UI control (start/stop button fe). Or the event could be disposed due of using an infinite loop to render the 3D world.

But, my problem is that when running the program, i get an `Invalid operation was unhandled` error. The issue is that there is an object which is a property of the main thread, thus the new thread might not access it.

from XAML file,

```
<Grid>
    <!-- ui controls omitted ... -->
    <Viewport3D Name="myViewport" ClipToBounds="True">
        <!-- all inits, camera, pos, ... -->
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

in main class;

```
/// <summary>this method is done to render the 3D app in other thread.</summary>
private void Runtime(Viewport3D vp) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("runtime ");
    Render3D r3d = new Render3D(vp);
    // actual startup
    while (keepRunning) {
        r3d.Init3D();
    }
}

/// <summary>this method toggles the game runtime</summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void StartOrStop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    keepRunning = !keepRunning;
    if (keepRunning) {
        buttonStartStop.Content = "Stop";
        // thread
        t1 = new Thread( () => Runtime(myViewport) );
        t1.Start();
    }
    else {
        buttonStartStop.Content = "Start";
        t1.Abort();
    }
}
```

The 3DViewport object is initialized in the XAML file. that's why i am passing it to the new thread, that it can create an object which is using that 3DViewport class.

Here below is a sample of the `Render3D` class.

```
// constructor
internal Render3D(Viewport3D v) {
    currViewport = v;
}

/// <summary>get called in loops to render gfx</summary>
internal void Init3D() {
    // clear rendered view
    ClearRenderWindow();
    // add landscape
    AddLandScape();
}

/// <summary>clear window to re-render gfx</summary>
private void ClearRenderWindow() {
    ModelVisual3D mv;

    // ***** error got caught here below ******
    for (int i = currViewport.Children.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        mv = (ModelVisual3D)currViewport.Children[i];
        if (mv.Content is DirectionalLight == false) currViewport.Children.Remove(mv);
    }
}
```

The error is caught at the `currViewport.Children.Count` method. As previously said, the issue is that the current thread doesn't have ownership of that object. It's the first time in my multithreading experience to face with this issue. I have searched around, but couldn't find a solution.

Does anyone know how to pass the ownership of the Viewport3D-object, or a good workaround ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would like to say that WPF is **not** a good framework for developing all but the simplest games... I would advise using a gaming framework like Microsoft's [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) instead.

However, if you insist on using WPF, then I would like to bring the [`CompositionTarget.Rendering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) event to your attention. It basically uses the frame rate of the host computer to render regulates graphics passes, avoiding the need to use timers.

You should also take a look at the [How to: Render on a Per Frame Interval Using CompositionTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms748838%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page at MSDN for more helpful information and code examples.

Also, please read this extract from the book 'WPF Control Development Unleashed: Building Advanced User Experiences':

> Some readers may recognize a similarity between this approach and higher-end graphics
>   subsystems like DirectX. Do not mistake CompositionTarget.Rendering for a good injection
>   point to create a WPF-based gaming graphics engine. High-end graphics and ultrahigh
>   frame rates are not the goal of this particular aspect of WPF animation.
>
> Similar to the DispatcherTimer approach, animations based on CompositionTarget.Rendering
>   are also not time-bound. However, these events are synced with the render thread resulting
>   in smoother animations than the DispatcherTimer. Also there is no need to start and
>   stop a timer, although you may have to detach and attach the event handler to improve
>   performance.

UPDATE >>>

Having discovered that this is just for a course project, I would ignore my previous comment and your code example so far. Don't try to create a new rendering system when there is one already. Instead, you should follow this approach:

Create data objects that implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and have `X`, `Y`, and `DirectionVector` (could be a `Size` struct) public properties.

Add a `Move` method (or `Swim` method for your `Fish` class) in which you update the data objects' `X` and `Y` properties dependant on the value of the `DirectionVector` property.

Add a `ListBox` control to your UI.

Create a collection property to hold your data objects, add items and bind the collection to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property.

Create a `DataTemplate` to define what your `Fish` objects look like... you can use the `Path` class to draw them and even use a `RotateTransform` to rotate them (the angle can be calculated from the `DirectionVector` property). In the `DataTemplate`, you can bind the `X` and `Y` properties to the `Margin' property.

Finally, add an infinite loop (possibly with a break out option) and in that loop, iterate through the collection of data objects and call `Move()` on each one. This will update the data objects' positions in the `ListBox`.

Comment: thank you for the reply. It's for my course project. I know that there are better alternatives (i even asked if i'm allowed to use XNA or DirectX because WPF is just too limited imo). It's a "diving" game, just swimming around and meeting fishes. :-) Gotcha look into that event method. But,, does it even require using a single thread application or am i wrong ?

Comment: Thank you again. i have worked it out and i can now render the things i want in 3D. But, i don't know what i should do with the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event. I fire it after each Move() call, but, what then ?

Comment: Good. Take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged) on CodeProject... in particular, the first three code sections. The idea is that each time the properties are updated (from the Move method), each property notifies the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The interface will then automatically update the UI to reflect the changes (if you have correctly bound the properties in the UI).

Comment: thank you again. i have added a small note at my question to say that your way of work works better and is, not only easy to perform, but also a way to have a good standard. I have combined it with the use of `CompositionTarget.Rendering` to achieve it.. Voted as answer.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, the only objects that can change thread allegiance in WPF are those that derive from `Freezable`. (E.g., `Model3D` is a freezable, and so, therefore, are things like `Light` and `GeometryModel3D`.)

Elements that participate directly in the visual tree do not derive from `Freezable`. They derive from Visual (usually, although not always, via `FrameworkElement`). Consequently, visual elements are forever associated with the thread on which you created them. Freezables are usually descriptive items that tell visual tree elements what to do. For example, brushes (whether solid, gradient fill, image brush or whatever) are freezables, but to do something with a brush you need to use it as a property of some visual element (i.e. something that's not a freezable) e.g., the `Fill` of a `Rectangle`.

So `Model3D` falls into this category - it is a description of a 3D model, but it doesn't actually know how to render itself. You provide this description to some visual element that does know how to render the model (e.g. `Viewport3D`).

So it's possible to build up `Model3D` on a worker thread, and then pass that over to the UI thread.

However, you can only start using a freezable object from some thread other than the one on which it was created after you have frozen it by calling `Freeze`. This, as the name suggests, prevents further modification. Once a freezable is frozen, it is no longer associated with any particular thread, so you can use it from whatever thread you like.

The intended usage model here is:

1. Build something complicated on a worker thread
2. Freeze it
3. Attach it to something that knows how to render it in the UI thread

This might be appropriate if you wanted to build a complex `Model3D` that was going to take a long time to construct, and you didn't want to make the application unresponsive while that was happening.

However, this is not of any use if you need the model to be modifiable as time goes on. If that's what you need (and it sounds like it is) then you tend to have no choice but to create the model on the UI thread - if you create a freezable that you never actually freeze (because you need the ability to change it) then you have to create it on the same thread that will render it. When you want to update the model, you either need to ensure updates are done on the UI thread, or you could use data binding, which is able to handle change notification events on any thread, and it will marshal those to the UI thread for you.

However, I'm wondering whether you really need multithreading at all. You give the reason as

> to provide a better UI control (start/stop button fe).

That's not really a reason to use a separate thread. There's nothing stopping the UI thread from performing updates to the model and also responding to UI input. You just need to make sure the code that updates the model regularly returns control to the event loop.

The only reason for using a separate thread would be if the calculations that determine what the updates to the model should be are computationally expensive. For example, if you're writing code that performs a complex and highly detailed simulation of some process, and then renders the result, it might make sense to perform the calculations on a worker thread to enable the UI to remain responsive. But even then, once those calculations are complete, you'd need to ensure that the updates you make to the model based on the results of those calculations are done on the UI thread, not the worker thread.

It may be worth considering whether you can get away with building a new model each time round. The user might not actually notice if you drop the old model and instantly replace it with a newly built model. That can enable you to build the entire model on the worker thread, because you can then freeze it. If you build a new model each time, it's safe to freeze, because any time you want to change something, you just build a new model instead of updating the old one.

Yet another variation is to have a model that consists mostly of frozen pieces, contained by some unfrozen top-level elements.

Comment: interesting. I have decided to do multithreading because the click events from UI get disposed before being handled due of using an infinite loop. If you know an easier workaround to catch the UI events (i don't know which methods or statements to use), then my issue is solved. Probably i have made myself difficult here ...

Comment: Don't use an infinite loop. Presumably the purpose of your loop is to keep updating the 3D model continuously to support movement? Rather than using a loop, just handle the CompositionTarget.Rendering event Sheridan mentions - this will call you once every frame until you remove your handler. In this event handler do all the work you would have done in one iteration of your infinite loop.